# Рекурсия в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, рекурсия

Столкнулся с такой задачей, не знаю как её выполнить
Есть таблица employees в ней поля

```
ID
NAME
CHIEF
BONUS
```

Поле CHIEF вторичный ключ ссылается на эту же таблицу с ID.
Нужно найти сотрудников, которые получают больше премии чем их руководитель.

Comment: А при чем тут рекурсия?

Comment: Запрос рекурсивный будет. Или я что то не понял

Comment: Вам нужно сделать JOIN таблицы саму на себя по полям CHIEF и ID, чтобы получить пары работчик-шеф и сравнить их премии-зарплаты, что еще вы хотите узнать.

Comment: @Vartlok Если "плоская схема" (начальник - руководитель) - тогда да. А если у начальника может быть свой начальник.... Скорее всего что нужно копать в сторону деревьев.

Comment: @androschuk даже в таком случае по поставки задачи надо найти только работник-начальник, даже если у начальника свой начальник, это будет другая пара.

Comment: Если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, то, пожалуйста, отметьте его "галочкой" рядом со "стрелочками" (которые "+" "-").

Comment: Если вам был дан исчерпывающий и правильный ответ, отметьте его как правильный для тех, кто в дальнейшем обнаружит данную тему.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Была когда-то примерно такая же задача на собеседовании в своё время, решается примерно так (рекурсия тут не нужна):

```
SELECT EMP1.ID, 
       EMP1.NAME
FROM   employees EMP1 
JOIN   employees EMP2
ON     EMP1.CHIEF = EMP2.ID
WHERE  EMP1.BONUS > EMP2.BONUS
```

Comment: Вы не обработали ситуацию, когда в таблице описана ветвистая структура. То есть в таблице больше 1го уровня иерархии

Comment: @IDrakonl - её незачем обрабатывать в таком случае иерархии. В подобной задаче руководитель - тот, кто идет следующий по грейду. В данном случае для руководителя его руководитель - будет в такой же паре, как и обычный сотрудник с его руководителем.

Comment: Признаю. Был не прав. Сам себя перехитрил. Ваше решение безусловно более разумно

Answer (score 6):

Задачу можно решить несколькими способами:
Самое разумное решение через join:

```
select e1.*
from   employees e1 
inner  join employees e2
on     e1.chiff = e2.id
where  e1.bonus > e2.bonus
```

Так же можно использовать `Connect by`, `рекурсивный with` или `скалярные подзапросы`.

`connect by`.
Если развернуть вложенный запрос, то будет видна логика
Получается примерно так:

```
with employees as (
  select 1 as ID, 'a' as name, null as CHIFF, 100 as Bonus from dual union all
  select 2 as ID, 'b' as name, '1' as CHIFF, 50 as Bonus from dual union all
  select 3 as ID, 'c' as name, '1' as CHIFF, 200 as Bonus from dual union all
  select 4 as ID, 'd' as name, '0' as CHIFF, 100 as Bonus from dual unioт all
  select 5 as ID, 'e' as name, '3' as CHIFF, 400 as Bonus from dual union all
  select 6 as ID, 'f' as name, '3' as CHIFF, 200 as Bonus from dual
)
select distinct 
       t.id, 
       t.name, 
       t.chiff, 
       t.bonus, 
       priorbonus as chiff_bonus 
from  (
        select lpad(' ', 3*level)||e.id as tree, e.*, 
               prior id, 
               prior bonus  
        from   employees e 
        connect by prior id=e.chiff
        and    prior bonus < bonus 
) t where priorid is not null
```

Помните, что рекурсия может привести к неожиданным результатам и очень долго работающим запросам.

Второй способ скалярные подзапросы. Примерно так:

```
select * 
from   (
         select e.*, 
                (select max(bonus) from employees e1 where e.chiff=e1.id) as chiff_bonus 
         from   employees e 
) t where t.bonus>chiff_bonus
```

`max(bonus)` для перестраховки