# Как сделать запрос который выводит сотрудников и их менеджеров(FIOсотрудников, FIO менеджеров)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица `Sotrudniki` - там есть `ID` сотрудников, `FIO` (сотрудников), и `ID_MANAGER`(ID менеджеров). Менеджеры  и есть сотрудники.

Например, ID сотрудников 100, 101, 102, 103 и их менеджер сотрудник под ID 100. Мне надо вывести FIO сотрудников и их менеджеров по имени(FIO).

Answer (score 5):

Лучше использовать `LEFT JOIN`, если нужно вывести и сотрудников без менеджеров. В противном случае заменить `LEFT JOIN` на `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
  s.fio as sotrudnik_id,
  m.fio as manager_id
FROM Sotrudniki s
LEFT JOIN Sotrudniki m
  ON s.id_manager = m.id
ORDER BY s.fio;
```

Comment: У меня нет же ФИО менеджеров. У меня только ФИО сотрудников , а у менеджеров только ID_MANAGER есть. Вот мне надо вывести сотрудников с их менеджерами. Некоторые сотрудники и есть менеджеры.

Comment: @user221601 Вы запрос то попробовали ? он выдаст именно то что вы просили ФИО сотрудника и рядом ФИО его менеджера.

Comment: @user221601 Всё верно. В этом запросе таблица объединяется сама с собой, к записи о сотруднике присоединяется запись о его менеджере. Но если в таблице есть сотрудники, у которых менеджер отсутствует (`ID_MANAGER` пусто), то в варианте с `LEFT JOIN` они будут в выборке, а в вариант с `INNER JOIN` не попадут. Довольно часто это отличие важно, поэтому на всякий случай решил про это написать. Подробнее о JOIN-ах можете почитать в специализированной литературе или документации.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  s1.fio,
  s2.fio
FROM Sotrudniki s1
JOIN Sotrudniki s2
  ON s1.id_manager = s2.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
SELECT s.fio AS sotrudnik_fio,
       m.fio AS manager_fio
FROM sotrudnik s LEFT JOIN sotrudnik m ON s.id_manager = m.id
ORDER BY m.id
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84304/1).

Ваш вопрос напоминает [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494241/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-oracle/494250), фактически дубликат.