# Как вывести начальника у которого больше чем у кого либо подчиненных?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица сотрудников `employee_tbl`. В ней есть следующие поля:

`id ,FIO_eployees, manager_id`.FIO менеджера не хранятся в отдельном поле. FIO менеджера берутся из поля FIO_employees. Так как менеджеры они тоже сотрудники.

Мне надо вывести  `FIO` менеджера , у которого больше всего подчиненных.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, какое у вас условие задачи.

Comment: Таблица сотрудников, FIO менеджера берутся из поля FIO_employees. Получается, что в записи сотрудников хранятся ФИО менеджера, а не ФИО этих самых сотрудников. В таком случае вам поможет запрос, с группировкой по FIO_eployees(ошибка в слове), подсчётом сгруппированных записей и выводом максимальной. Но не думаю, что это то, что надо.

Comment: нет  у меня там всего три поля. ФИО менеджеров берутся из поля ФИО  сотрудников. Так как некоторые сотрудники и есть менеджеры.

Comment: @user221704, вам уже сделали запрос с проверкой на sqlfiddle, который корректно отрабатывает.

Comment: @Denis ну не явная конечно копия, но при желании можно воспользоваться образцом и получить желаемый результат

Comment: @Bald в котором надо лишь переименовать названия таблицы и столбцов.

Comment: ну вроде в предыдущем вопросе было получения фио менеджера, а сейчас надо посчитать количество подчиненных. а если по существу то закрыть бы конечно надо но не как копию

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать запрос который выводит сотрудников и их менеджеров(FIOсотрудников, FIO менеджеров)?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571678/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2fio%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-f)

Answer (score 4):

Всё очень просто:
1) Это подзапрос кол-во подчинённых

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee_tbl AS w WHERE w.manager_id= m.id
```

2) Чтобы получить с максимальным числом - сортируем по убыванию

```
ORDER BY подзапрос DESC
```

3) Нам нужен самый-самый, т.е. один

```
LIMIT 1
```

В итоге получаем:

```
SELECT FIO_employees FROM employee_tbl AS m 
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee_tbl AS w WHERE w.manager_id= m.id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Псевдонимы таблиц m -это менеджер, w - рядовой работник

---

### ВАРИАНТ №2

если всё же надо найти несколько менеджеров с одинаковым числом подчинённых

1 строка - менеджеры

2 строка - кол-во подчинённых

последняя строка - максимальное кол-во подчинённых

```
SELECT FIO_employees FROM employee_tbl AS m WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee_tbl AS w WHERE w.manager_id= m.id) 
= 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as maxw FROM employee_tbl AS w GROUP BY w.manager_id ORDER BY maxw DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: А если у нас несколько начальников, с максимальным количеством подчиненных?

Comment: В вопросе в единственном числе.

Comment: Ну, обычно так и дается условие, особенно на собеседовании. Но могут быть случаи, когда таких людей несколько. `Вывести  FIO менеджеров , у которых больше всего подчиненных.` - звучит немного некорректно.

Comment: Добавил ещё один ответ

Comment: @Mrak старайтесь умещать всё в одном ответе, не плодите их.

Comment: а что за head??

Comment: это manager_id. Исправил.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e_2.FIO_eployees
FROM employee_tbl As e_1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_tbl As e_2 ON e_1.manager_id = e_2.id
GROUP BY e_1.manager_id, e_2.FIO_eployees
HAVING COUNT(e_1.ID) = 
            (SELECT COUNT(id) 
             FROM employee_tbl 
             GROUP BY manager_id 
             ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
             LIMIT 1)
```

-- В том случае если нам не нужна информация о сотрудниках без начальника :

```
SELECT e_2.FIO_eployees
FROM employee_tbl As e_1
    INNER JOIN employee_tbl As e_2 ON e_1.manager_id = e_2.id
GROUP BY e_1.manager_id, e_2.FIO_eployees
HAVING COUNT(e_1.ID) = 
            (SELECT COUNT(id) 
             FROM employee_tbl
             WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL 
             GROUP BY manager_id                  
             ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
             LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: а если больше всего будет у null?

Comment: @Denis, Кстати, этот же вопрос и к вам, надо пожалуй использовать LEFT OUTER

Comment: У меня не получилось вы меня правильно поняли? Столбец "dbo.TABLE2.FIO" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY- вот такую ошибку показывает

Comment: У меня стоит условие на `null`, на sqlfiddle срабатывает корректно.

Comment: @user221704, уже подправил, в GROUP BY замените fio на FIO_eployees

Comment: У меня нет же такого поля как ФИО менеджеров. Сначала надо сделать  INNER JOIN и от туда вывести ФИО сотрудников в моем случае SELECT S.ID,
       S.FIO,
    M.FIO
  FROM [dbo].[TABLE2] S inner JOIN [dbo].[TABLE2] M ON M.ID=S.ID_MANAGER
  ORDER BY S.ID

Comment: @user221704, да сначала надо сделать соединение, какое зависит от условия задачи, нужна информация о начальниках (то есть `manager_id = null` ) - `LEFT OUTER`, не нужна - `INNER`, потому и написано два запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть случай, когда будут сами менеджеры, значит у них `id_manager` будет `null`. Ограничение на `id_manager IS NOT NULL` исходит из этих соображений.

```
SELECT m.fio
FROM sotrudnik s JOIN sotrudnik m ON s.id_manager = m.id
GROUP BY s.id_manager
HAVING COUNT(s.id) = (SELECT MAX(cnt)
                      FROM (SELECT id_manager, count(id) AS cnt
                            FROM sotrudnik
                            WHERE id_manager IS NOT NULL
                            GROUP BY id_manager) t)
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84304/7/0)